# Complicated issue in breaking out of an iFrame and loading the 'return url'

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've the following issue using iframes.

I've an iFrame 'frameParent'. Inside frameParent i've a page 'parentPage.aspx' with several links in the format

```
http://test.aspx?pageURL=http://something.aspx?returnUrl=http://domain/parentPage.aspx
```

So when you click the link test.aspx gets loaded inside frameParent. Inside test.aspx i've a frame 'childFrame'. Using a JS function in test.aspx, i take the pageURL

```
http://something.aspx?returnUrl=http://domain/parentPage.aspx
```

and set it as the src for childFrame.

So something.aspx gets loaded inside 'childFrame' with returnUrl as the same parentPage.aspx.

After clicking OK or Cancel in something.aspx i return back to parentPage.aspx. But i dont want to load parentPage.aspx in childFrame (since something.aspx is in childFrame). I want to break out and load it in the parentFrame.

How can i do that?

Hope i've explained well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="stuff" target="_parent">loads one frame up</a>
<a href="stuff" target="_top">loads in the very top frame if there are multiple nested frames.</a>
```